# Способы порождения достоверных гипотез

Tags: искусственный-интеллект, книги

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие существуют способы порождения достоверных гипотез, а так же их преимущества/недостатки? Какую русскоязычную литературу посоветуете почитать на эту тему?

Comment: Ну и вопросики у вас! В Google пока что обучили нейронную сеть лишь [котиков распознавать][1], а вы уже хотите выдвигать теории с помощью AI.


  [1]: http://lenta.ru/news/2012/06/27/ggl/

Comment: @Asen, перед тем как чушь писать, хоть бы погуглил на словосочетание «ДСМ-метод.»

Comment: http://www.aiportal.ru/downloads/books/hypothesis-generation-by-mill-peirce-popper.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Нашел по крайней мере 2 метода:

- GUHA-метод
- ДСМ-метод

**Литература**:

[Гаек П., Гавранек Т. Автоматическое образование гипотез. Математические основы общей теории (GUHA метод)](http://www.twirpx.com/file/255549/)

[ДСМ-метод автоматического порождения гипотез. Логические и эпистемологические основания](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4508305/)

[Автоматическое порождение гипотез в интеллектуальных системах](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4362523/)

[Достоверный и правдоподобный вывод в интеллектуальных системах](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4650130/)

Из недостатков ДСМ-метода можно отметить неприменимость в условиях противоречий в обучающих примерах, а так же

> ДСМ-метод, не использующий
> статистических критериев, может быть
> «введён в заблуждение» шумовыми
> данными.

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что ДСМ-метод вам поможет в выдвижении "достоверных" гипотез. Чтобы гипотеза стала достоверной, её надо формально доказать; но это будет уже не гипотеза, а теорема. А что касаемо гипотез, я думаю, в большинстве случаев сгодится нейросеть или метод опорных векторов или дерево выбора, если хочется увидеть саму гипотезу.